Is it always possible to get from integer $x$ to $x^2$ by repeatedly multiplying by $2$ or subtracting $3$?
So, I had come across this mathematical problem.

Given a number $x$, you are allowed two operations:

Multiply by $2$, or
Subtract by $3$.

Find the minimum number of steps to reach $121$ from $11$.

I got the solution:
$$11 \to 8 \to 5 \to 10 \to 20 \to 17 \to 34 \to 31 \to 62 \to 124 \to 121$$
I tried to delve deeper into the question.
I discovered that it's always not possible(at least for me) to reach a particular number from a given starting number, and interestingly, we see loops.
Take $5$ and try reaching $18$. I am trying to work it out backward here (it makes it easier for me). Here you can divide by $3$ or add $3$ (if you are working in reverse).
$$\begin{align}
&18 \to 9 \to 12 \to 6 \to 3 \to 6 \to 3 \to 6 \to 3 \\
&18 \to 9 \to 12 \to 15 \to 18 \to 9 \to 12 \to \cdots
\end{align}$$
I find myself always stuck on loops, which is interesting, in this problem.
But what I found is, that reaching perfect squares from their square root, is actually quite easy.
Take $7$ to $49$. Again, working in reverse (it's easier for me):
$$49 \to 52 \to 26 \to 13 \to 16 \to 8 \to 4 \to 7$$
We got a solution,
$$7 \to 4 \to 8 \to 16 \to 16 \to 26 \to 52 \to 49$$
Now, take $30$ to $900$. Working in reverse:
$$900 \to 450 \to 225 \to 228 \to 114 \to 57 \to 60 \to 30$$
Done.
Here is my question:

Is it always possible to find solutions from $x$ to $x^2$ in this system, and is there any way to determine when we are going to get loops?


You can't get from a number not divisible by $3$ to a number divisible by $3.$ You can't get from a number divisible by $3$ to a number not divisible by $3.$ Any other pairs can be solved.

And despite the initial example if $11$ and $121,$ this question doesn't seem to be about squares as mentioned in your title. Certainly, you $5$ and $18$ are not squares. But $n$ is divisible by $3$ iff $n^2$ is divisible by $3,$ so you can always get from $n$ to $n^2$ and back.

@ThomasAndrews Stupid mistake, sorry.

If $m,n$ is your start and goal, and neither is divisible by $3,$ then you can find a $k$ such that $2^km>n$ and $2^km\equiv n\pmod{3}.$ Then subtract enough $3$s. So you can always do it by first doing multiples of $2$ and then subtacting $3$s.

The same technique also works for $m,n$ both divisible by $3.$

If your starting number is not divisible by $3$ and your target is so divisible, you can't get there. The target divisible by $3$ can be generated only by a preceding number divisible by $3$. By a similar argument, you fail if the starting number is divisible by $3$ and the target is not.
Everything else, though, is achievable. Meaning you can have both numbers divisible by $3$ or both not divisible by $3$ (additional factors of $3$ in either number, such as with multiples of $9$, do not matter). For instance, to get from $12$ to $18$ where both numbers are divisible by $3$:
$12\to24\to21\to18$
Or to get from $11$ to $17$ where they areboth not divisible by $3$:
$11\to22\to44*\to41\to38\to...\to17$
*Congruent with $17\bmod3$
So since both $n$ and $n^2$ have the same answer to divisibility by $3$, that combination always admits a solution. For $n=14$, which is nit a multiple of $3$, let us say:
$14\to28\to56\to224\to448\to445\to442\to...\to199\to196$
where you switch from multiplication to subtraction once you get a number greater than or equal to the target and $\equiv1\bmod 3$ (here $448$).
To square a multiple of $3$, any number greater than or equal to the squared value is where you would switch:
$12\to24\to48\to96\to192\to189\to186\to...\to147\to144$
There is no guarantee that doing all the multiplications first and then all the subtractions is the minimal number of steps.

Please be much more precise than "fair game" or "good to go". What precisely is your answer to the OP's question, and where is your proof of such.? Examples are not proofs.

Hoping my rewordings satisfy. If not OlI may have to delete.

I claim that you can always get from $m$ to $n$ by doubling and subtracting 3 if either $m$ and $n$ are both multiples of 3 or neither one is.
First,  you can get from 1 to any positive integer not divisible by 3.  Proof by induction: assume you can get to $1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, \ldots, 6n-5, 6n-4, 6n-2$ - that is, every positive integer not divisble by 3 up to $6n-2$.   We want to show you can reach $6n-1, 6n+1, 6n+2, 6n+4$.
$6n+2$ and $6n+4$ can be reached by doubling $3n+1$ and $3n+2$, and $6n-1$ and $6n+1$ can be reached by subtracting 3 from these.
You need a suitable base case for the induction - $n = 2$, I believe, will do.  The trajectory  1-2-4-8-5-10-7 takes care of that.
Second, you can get to 1 from any positive integer not divisible by 3.      If it's of the form $3n+1$, just subtract 3 repeatedly; if it's of the form $3n+2$, double it, then subtract 3 repeatedly.
Putting these together, you can get from any non-multiple of 3 to any other non-multiple of 3 by going through 1.
Furthermore, you can get from any multiple of 3 to any other.  This is easier - just double repeatedly until you have a number larger than your target, and subtract 3 until you hit it.
